I want to align Mathematics and class X vertically
I want to align Mathematics and class X vertically and Max marks and time vertically. How can I do it plz help me.

\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[a4paper,
                bindingoffset=0.2in,
                left=0.2in,
                right=0.5in,
                top=1in,
                bottom=1in,
                footskip=.25in]{geometry}
    \begin{document}
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    \title {Maple Institute Of Education}   
    \includegraphics[width=4cm, height=2.2cm]{maple}
    \maketitle
    
    
    
    Mathematics    \hspace{5cm}     Max Marks : 30\\ 
    Class X         \hspace{6.2cm}     Time : 1 hour
    \\
    
    \textbf{General Instructions}
    
    All Questions are necessary.
    
    
    
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item In the given figure the tangent at a point C of a circle and diameter when extended intersect at P. If $\angle PCA = 110 ^\circ$, find $\angle CBA.$
    
    \includegraphics[width=8cm, height=4.5cm]{1}
    
    \item AB is a diameter and AC is a chord of a circle with centre O such that $\angle BAC= 30^\circ.$ The tangent at C intersects AB produced ata point D. Prove that BC=BD.
    
    \item If $d_1,d_2 (d_2 > d_1)$ be the diameters of two concentric circles and C be the length of a chord of a circle which is tangent to the other circle, prove that $d_2^2 = c^2 + d_1^2.$
    
    \item A circle is inscribed in triangle ABC having sides 8 cm, 10 cm and 12 cm as shown in figure. Find AD, BE and CF.
    \includegraphics[width=8cm, height=4.5cm]{4}
    
    \item If an isosceles triangle ABC in which AB = AC = 6 cm is inscribed in a circle of radius 9 cm, find the area of the triangle. 
    
    \item In the given figure, tangents PQ and PR are drawn from an external point P to a circle with centre O such that $\angle RPQ = 30^\circ$. A chord RS is drawn parallel to the tangent PQ. Find $\angle RQS$.  
    \includegraphics[width=8cm, height=4.5cm]{6}
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{document}


tabular environment is one of the easy fix

@MadyYuvi Can you provide full answer. I am a beginner in latex.

Please try with the below suggestion:
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[a4paper,
                bindingoffset=0.2in,
                left=0.2in,
                right=0.5in,
                top=1in,
                bottom=1in,
                footskip=.25in]{geometry}
    \begin{document}
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    \title {Maple Institute Of Education}   
    \includegraphics[width=4cm, height=2.2cm]{maple}
    \maketitle
    
    
\noindent\begin{tabular*}{0.6\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep\fill}ll@{}}
    Mathematics &     Max Marks : 30\\ 
    Class X      &     Time : 1 hour
\end{tabular*}

\bigskip
    
    \textbf{General Instructions}
....
....
\end{document}

Note that I've modified the part what you mentioned in your question, other things, I've retained as is.

thanks......................
